# Asking for cache data failed | Assuming drive cache : write through. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS GUI doesnot appear

Tags: 12.04, boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my hard drive partition of 10 gb.
I was uninstalling some software and after that this messages started coming up on a black full screen.

```
Asking for cache data failed
Assuming drive cache : write through
```

I restarted my machine and when I boot into Ubuntu this messages shows up.
only command line is available.
I can enter my username and password on the command line and the prompt appears.

```
user@user-pc$:
```

but the GUI doesn't shows up.

What to do? Please help.

Comment: `I was uninstalling some software` "some"? Please be specific. Like dit you uninstall the desktop software? (looks like it...).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using  a server installation. If you deleted software and you also deleted the desktop you can re-install it with..

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After you reboot you will see a desktop again.

---

This...

> Asking for cache data failed
>
> Assuming drive cache : write through

has nothing to do with it.